# The equivalent resistance between terminals A and B?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis

Resistors R2,R3,R4 are connected in series.  I'm not sure how to find the equivalent resistance of between terminals A and B, because of the short circuit.  However, I suspect the answer is R1+R4 because of the short circuit.  I am confused about this, can someone help me?  Thanks!

[image]

EDIT: Thanks for pointing that out.  My drawing is indeed incorrect.  Lets say the resistor R4 which is connected in series to R2, R3 will now be called R5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your drawing is correct, then the resistance between A & B is simply R1 + R4. R2, R32 and R4 are not relevant since they are shorted out. Note, however, that there are 2 resistors with the same label, R4.

Comment: is correct. Just as an exercise you can consider the short to be a resistor of almost 0 resistance. eg. 0.00001ohm then use the parrallel resistance rule to calculate the total resistance for that segment (R0-R2-R3-R5. The result should show that the combined resistance will be virtually the same as 0.00001ohm thereby proving you can ignore the R2-R3-R5 leg in this case.